# OpenCL cannot find GPU device: NVIDIA GPU (Quadro K4000) + Visual Studio 2015

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

Just started to learn OpenCL and setup a Visual Studio project using VS2015. Somehow, the code can find only 1 platform (I guess it should be the CPU), and cannot find the GPU device. Can someone please help? The detailed information is as follows:

1. GPU: Nvidia Quadro K4000
2. CUDA Installation

   > CUDA is at: “`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5`”
   >
   > OpenCL related files are located at "`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\include\CL`" and "`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\lib\Win32`" (assuming 32bit system)
   >
   > The installer created two environment  variables “`CUDA_PATH`” and “`CUDA_PATH_V7_5`”. They both point to the above location.
3. In Visual Studio, the project is set up as

   > "**Project Properties**" -> "**C/C++**" -> "**Additional Include Directories**" -> "`$(CUDA_PATH)\include`"
   >
   > "**Project Properties**" -> "**Linker**" -> "**Additional Library Directories**" -> "`$(CUDA_PATH)\lib\Win32`"
   >
   > "**Project Properties**" -> "**Linker**" -> "**Input**" -> "**Additional Dependencies**" -> "`OpenCL.lib`"

The code is very simple:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cl_int err;
    cl_uint numPlatforms;

    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);

    if (CL_SUCCESS == err)
        cout << "Detected OpenCL platforms: " << numPlatforms  << endl;
    else
        cout << "Error calling clGetPlatformIDs. Error code:" << err << endl;


    cl_device_id device = NULL;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);
    if (err == CL_SUCCESS)
        cout << device << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs, but it cannot the GPU device. Specifically, the returned value of variable `device` is `device = 0x00000000 <NULL>`. What would be the problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the way you use the OpenCL API.

You need to obtain a valid `cl_platform_id` object which it needs to be used to retrieve a `cl_device_id`. You are always passing `NULL`, this can't work.

The first time you invoke the `clGetPlatformIds`, you do it in order to obtain the number of platforms in the system. After than you need to invoke the method again in order to retrieve the actual `cl_platform_id`s:

```
size_t numPlatforms;
err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
assert(numPlatforms > 0);
cl_platform_id platform_ids[numPlatforms];
err = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platform_ids, NULL);
```

However, if you already know there is going to be only one platform in the system, then you can do speedup things as follows, but make sure to check for errors:

```
cl_platform_id platform_id;
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, NULL);
assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
```

After you have obtained a platform you need to follow the same procedure to first obtain the number of devices and then retrieve the list of OpenCL devices (which you then will need to build a `cl_context`, queues...):

```
// Note: this has to be done for each `cl_platform_id`
// until you find the device you were looking for
size_t numDevices;
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &numDevices);
assert(numDevices > 0);
cl_device_id devices[numDevices];
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, numDevices, devices, NULL);
```

I guess you understand the procedure now. If like above, you already know that there is only 1 GPU device in the system, you can directly get its `cl_device_id` as follows:

```
cl_device_id device;
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);
assert(err == CL_SUCCESS);
```